# I want To use EF Core 3.1 in Asp Net Core With Database First Approach And also wants to use Identity in my Project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, ef-core-3.1

I have used ef core in my asp.Net Core project . What I want to do is , i wants to use Database First Approch with EF Core And Identity but whenever i am scaffolding my db Context it is overriding all previous changes i have made for Identity such as user class inheriting from IdentityUser and all .And I am Also new to this so u can provide some resources to refer.

Answer (score 0):

"The main problem with database first approach : You should never change the model manually and start renaming things etc. Except if you are 100 % sure that your database won't change anymore. If you'r not 100 % sure, just code with the model that has been auto-generated.

Re-Scaffolding will overwrite any changes made directly in the model class, erasing all what you have changed or added."

Check out this explanation, I hope it helps:
https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/40344526/entity-framework-core-database-first-update-after-initial-scaffold-